# automatically call pyvenv-activate on elpy-mode-hook

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs, elpy, pyvenv

I am new to emacs and try to learn some elisp to configure it.

I wanted to automatically activate a python virtual environment when entering `elpy-mode`.

I have tried all kinds of variations of the following code

```
(use-package elpy
  :init
  (elpy-enable)
  :config
  (add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (let* ((my-venv-root (locate-dominating-file buffer-file-name "venv"))
                     (my-venv (file-name-as-directory (file-name-concat my-venv-root "venv"))))
                 (message (concat "Venv Root: " my-venv-root))
                 (message (concat "Venv: " my-venv))
                 (when my-venv
                   (message "Try to activate Virtual Environment")
                   (pyvenv-activate my-venv))))))
```

The manual way `M-x pyvenv-activate` `RET` `/path/to/project/venv` `RET` followed by `C-c C-c` works just fine.

But if I put the above code in my `init.el` file I keep getting the Error `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` when trying to run a python file/buffer using `C-c C-c`

The messages yield correct looking values for `my-venv-root` and `my-venv`. For Example:

```
Venv Root: ~/Documents/Code/Test/
Venv: ~/Documents/Code/Test/venv/
Try to activate Virtual Environment
```

I am using Debian 12 with emacs 28.2 installed from the debian repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a/the solution.

**TL;DR:**

Wrapped the code inside `(when buffer-file-name ...`.

**A little more detailed:**

For some reason the `elpy-mode-hook` gets called when `C-c C-c` opens the `Inferior Python Shell` (But `C-h m` didn't show `elpy`, ...).
It triggered the hook again with `buffer-file-name` returning `nil`, because the `Inferior Python Shell` has no file name associated with it.

My solution was to wrap everything in `(when buffer-file-name ...`.

So my - now working - config looks like that:

```
(use-package elpy
  :init
  (elpy-enable)
  :config
  (pyvenv-mode t)
  (add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook
        (lambda ()
          (when buffer-file-name
            (let* ((my-venv-root (locate-dominating-file buffer-file-name "venv"))
                   (my-venv (file-name-as-directory (file-name-concat my-venv-root "venv"))))
            (message (concat "Venv Root: " my-venv-root))
            (message (concat "Venv: " my-venv))
            (when my-venv
              (message "Try to activate Virtual Environment")
              (pyvenv-activate my-venv)))))))
```

I do not fully understand how this could happen, 'cause this is what `C-h m` gives me in the `Inferior Python Shell`:

```
Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
Blink-Cursor Company Compilation-Shell Display-Line-Numbers
Electric-Indent File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Company
Global-Display-Line-Numbers Global-Eldoc Global-Font-Lock
Global-Hl-Line Line-Number Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel Override-Global Pyvenv
Recentf Save-Place Savehist Shell-Dirtrack Show-Paren Tool-Bar Tooltip
Transient-Mark Which-Key Windmove

(Information about these minor modes follows the major mode info.)

Inferior Python mode defined in ‘python.el’:
Major mode for Python inferior process.
Runs a Python interpreter as a subprocess of Emacs, with Python
I/O through an Emacs buffer.  Variables ‘python-shell-interpreter’
and ‘python-shell-interpreter-args’ control which Python
interpreter is run.  Variables
‘python-shell-prompt-regexp’,
‘python-shell-prompt-output-regexp’,
‘python-shell-prompt-block-regexp’,
‘python-shell-font-lock-enable’,
‘python-shell-completion-setup-code’,
‘python-shell-completion-string-code’,
‘python-eldoc-setup-code’, ‘python-eldoc-string-code’,
‘python-ffap-setup-code’ and ‘python-ffap-string-code’ can
customize this mode for different Python interpreters.

...
```

So no `Elpy` here, like in `C-h m` in a `something.py`-Buffer:

```
Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
Blink-Cursor Company Display-Line-Numbers Eldoc Electric-Indent Elpy
File-Name-Shadow Flymake Font-Lock Global-Company
Global-Display-Line-Numbers Global-Eldoc Global-Font-Lock
Global-Hl-Line Highlight-Indentation Line-Number Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel
Override-Global Pyvenv Recentf Save-Place Savehist Shell-Dirtrack
Show-Paren Tool-Bar Tooltip Transient-Mark Which-Key Windmove Yas

(Information about these minor modes follows the major mode info.)

Python mode defined in ‘python.el’:
Major mode for editing Python files.

...
```

But it works for me.